# Anaconda Environment - SKLearn Functions are Present but can't Import

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn

trying to import two things off Sklearn.  i have the most current version installed. The exact error i get is:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidTransformer, TfidVectorizer
ImportError: cannot import name 'TfidTransformer' from 'sklearn.feature_extraction.text' 
(C:\Users\peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py)
```

I did a search, and there are some old posts from about 2 years back (or earlier) where it looks like the user's problem was that they didn't have the most recent version of sklearn installed.  I do, and i can confirm that when i check the text.py file in the sklearn directory within `C:\user\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction`, i can see both `TFidTransformer` and `TfidVectorizer` present in the file.  Going crazy trying to figure out why i can't import these, can someone please help?

Also FYI in the same script, i'm importing (successfully), the CountVectorizer, which also comes from feature_extraction.  Can someone please help?  Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Are you sure the version of python you're using to run your code is the same as the version the module is installed for?  From your note about site packages, it looks like you're use the base environment in Anaconda, so you're probably find on that account.  I always try checking by doing `where python` and `where pip`.  Also sometimes important to verify the correct python and pip versions and that they match what you expect with `python -V` and `pip -V`.  Have you tried importing other classes out of the `text` module?

Comment: thanks for the quick response!  i checked both versions using python -V(3.7.4)  and pip -V(19.2.3 for python 3.7), so i assume that's ok?  when i hit where python or where pip, i don't get anything back.  i actually am importing another class out of that text module, the countvectorizer is imported just fine, which is why this is so confusing.  same exact library/file.

Comment: Can you do `conda list` to view your installed packages and versions?  What does it list for sklearn?

Comment: scikit-learn              0.22.2.post1             pypi_0    pypi

Comment: so Looking through the `text.py` module, it looks like the classes you're looking for are called [`TfidfTransformer`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.22.2.post1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1329) and [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.22.2.post1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1537).  Seems like a spelling mistake in your code?

Comment: is the pypi channel the problem?  i noticed that my other packages that i'm using (pandas, numpy, matplotlib, etc), aren't in that channel.

Comment: I think pypi just means that you installed it through pip rather than through conda.

Comment: I've checked the spelling multiple times, and it's definitely spelled properly (including the capital T in transformer and capital V in vectorizer).

Comment: nevermind...i do see it.  there's an extra f.  i'm an idiot.  thankx so much for your help!

Comment: I posted it as an answer so that other folks can see it's resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the `text.py` module, it looks like the classes you're looking for are called [`TfidfTransformer`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.22.2.post1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1329) and [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.22.2.post1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1537).  Seems like a spelling mistake in your code?